# How to reset the Windows 10 administrator password for a VM in Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-10, boot, virtual-machine, passwords, hyper-v

A few months ago I created a Windows 10 VM to host a development version of an enterprise software platform. I set up this software with help from an outside rep, and came back a few months ago having forgotten the password to the VM. Ideally, I'd like to reset the password for the VM, and not wipe it (since that would require engaging the rep again unnecessarily). I have explored several options:

- PCUnlocker
- Reset Windows Password
- NTPasswd ([http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/](http://pogostick.net/%7Epnh/ntpasswd/))

Each of these are bootable ISOs that claim to be able to reset the password on a Windows 10 install if booted.

I've verified that the properties of the ISO files do not contain the `P` attribute, and that they have been Unblocked in the Properties dialogue.

I've set the boot order for the VM as follows: [image: boot order picture]

When I boot the VM, either cold, or with a Reset, Stop/Start etc, it boots directly to the login screen, seemingly skipping the disk in the drive.

I'm sure this is due to a misconfiguration on my part, though I'm not sure what.

If this doesn't work, is there a way to copy all files and registry settings over to a new VM with a new password?

Comment: Your boot order has the Windows (EFI) bootloader first. That it boots Windows directly therefore shouldn't be a surprise. If you want to use any bootable ISO then that one should be the first, obviously.

Comment: The solution is the same for a physical machine, you change the boot order, and use a Windows ISO to enable the built-in Administrator account

Comment: I've tried it with the ISO at the top of the list, and it still doesn't boot into the alternate. Secure Boot is off, too. I think this question should not be closed, as the closure assumes you can boot from an ISO.